# GroupBy and Cut in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to group a set of things and perform cuts within the groups dynamically based on the min, max and average of both (min and max) value.

My dataset looks something like this:

```
Country     Value
Uganda       210
Kenya        423
Kenya        315 
Tanzania     780 
Uganda       124
Uganda       213
Tanzania     978 
Kenya        524
```

What I expect is in which range does each value fall, above or below mid-value:

```
Country      Value        Range
Uganda        210        (168.5, 213)
Uganda        124        (124, 168.5)
Uganda        213        (168.5, 213)
Kenya         423        (419.5, 524)
Kenya         315        (315, 419.5)
Kenya         524        (419.5, 524)
Tanzania      780        (780, 879)
Tanzania      978        (879, 980)
```

I am able to achieve this if I am doing it with a loop iterating over each group. I am also able to achieve the cuts based on the min and max value over the entire dataset but not individual groups. However, I was wondering if it can be done in a line or two using pandas and not use loops.

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: The second table is the expected result.

Comment: ok, the second one is sorted how?

Comment: Just a grouping, not expecting any kind of sort. Just an example. What I mainly need is which range the concerned value falls under.

Comment: could you show the for loop. cannot figure out what you exacty need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
df['range'] = df.groupby('country')[['value']].transform(lambda x: pd.cut(x, bins = 2).astype(str))
```

Comment: might be a possible duplicate though, take a look at my question a while back; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303633/conditionally-binning

Answer (score 4):

Try this;

```
data['Range'] = data.groupby('Country').Value.apply(pd.cut, bins=2)
```

Comment: I figured it out already. However, I checked your solution as well and it works. I will post my answer as well.

Comment: This solution gives me ``` ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis```